# cant import/install python libraries for another python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I got python 3.3.3 package as part of binary package. (http://siremol.org/Sire/Download.html) I tried lot of things but could not import or install additional libraries for this python package. I installed anaconda as well but nothing help me. When I import libraries (e.g numpy, matplotlib ..) from any other location on my system it gives me the following error;

ImportError: cannot import name multiarray

i dont know how I can do it. Please let me know if you need some details on files present in my installed package. I have pip, easy install files but they seems not working. Any possible guidelines to solve the issue ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to install libraries for version 3.

For example, using pip3:

```
pip3 install numpy #will install a package for Python3
```

Every install tool should have a switch what version of Python should it install libraries for.

Comment: I installed this way as well. Do i need to install in particular directory ? if so then how I can control route to my target directory ?

Comment: No need for that. The packages should be installed. If they are not, your whole installation may be broken.